# Map areas too low quality in Google Looker Studio

Tags: google-data-studio

Why are the local government area (LGA) shapes displayed in Google Looker Studio's Geo chart (using Filled areas) so low quality / fidelity, even when zoomed in? Basically each area has insufficient vector data to display it in a usable manner.

My data source is a CSV with two columns:

1. LGA (type = Geo > Country subdivision (2nd level))
2. n   (type = Aggregation > Sum)

For what it's worth, the shaded areas *are* in the right places. This screenshot shows Inner West, Woollahra and Randwick, for example.

[image: Geo chart showing poor quality areas]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured this out myself. The Geo map has a limit of 1 million vertices:

https://support.google.com/looker-studio/answer/9713352?hl=en#geo-limits&zippy=%2Cin-this-article%2Cconfigure-a-filled-area-map

Once I filter out anything outside New South Wales, this cuts down on the number of polygons required to be drawn and it improves the quality / fidelity of the LGA shapes:

[image]

Comment: Good job figuring it out!